# Express app not working on local network without internet

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, localhost, local

I have an express app with which I want other computers in the same WIFI Network to connect to it but without the internet being available.

The main PC which is hosting the app has the following fixed IP: 192.168.1.60

And I have done the following code in my server.js

```
app.listen(5000, '192.168.1.60' () => {
  console.log(`Server launched with port 5000`);
});
```

So whenever I try to access the app from another machine, it does not load unless I have internet.

Is there a way to make it work without the internet?

Comment: Interesting question, but perhaps slightly off-topic for SO, maybe ask this at [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/).

Answer (score 0):

```
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('Hello User!')
})
app.listen(5000, () => {
  console.log(`Server launched with port ${port}`)
})
```

Make sure you enter following URL http://192.168.1.60:5000 in your browser

Comment: That's what I'm doing, but I want it to be accessed without internet because at the moment I can only do it with internet available